# Moving a database from Wamp to One.com

Tags: drupal, phpmyadmin, wampserver, drush

I have a domain in one.com so as phpmyadmin from there. i installed drupal drush and wamp but the problem is i have got a phpmyadmin from wamp too, how can i make this work/ redirect/ move over to my one.com ? It's just before I go and install drush I want to make sure that I will be able to connected with my domain one.com server later on or even do it before. I don't even know how to stat this so I didn't tried anything just yet as I don't want to ruin it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Dont understand the question, can you add more details and be more specific

Comment: Doesn't you one.com package come with Apache/MySQL/PHP, if so why are you trying to install WAMPServer it is not necessary, everything is already there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a backup from the database which contains all the querys to generate the database. In the database manager on one.com you can run this script and the db with all content will be restored.